# Vega-tooltip in React application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, vega-lite

I have a React application that uses vega-lite for data visualizations. I tried to use the official tooltip addon for vega (https://github.com/vega/vega-tooltip), however I have no idea how to do it in a React component.

This is the component I have:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import VegaLite from 'react-vega-lite';

const VegaChart = ({data, spec}) => {
return(
<div className="vega-chart-wrapper">
<VegaLite spec={spec} data={data} />
</div>
)
}

VegaChart.propTypes = {
data: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
spec: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}

export default VegaChart;
```

From the documentation of vega-tooltip, it says that I can install the module and then I have to do this:

```
<!-- Placeholder for my scatter plot -->
<div id="vis-scatter"></div>

var opt = {
  mode: "vega-lite",
};
vega.embed("#vis-scatter", vlSpec, opt, function(error, result) {
  // result.view is the Vega View, vlSpec is the original Vega-Lite specification
  vegaTooltip.vegaLite(result.view, vlSpec);
});
```

This looks like the standard way to integrate in a jQuery application, but this is not gonna work in a React component. Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [react-vega and react-vega tooltips](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53642760/react-vega-and-react-vega-tooltips)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/53709494/866989 for a solution

Comment: Finally a solution, year and a half later. Strange how my question is marked as duplicate though, it should be the other way around....

Answer (score 0):

Your `react-vega-lite` must already include `vega-lite`. So

`import * as vega from 'vega-lite';`

And put the rest in `componentDidMount` of your `VegaChart`

Comment: Nope, this is not working. The whole process requires some additional 'vega-embed' library, which is simply not Web-component ready, so it expects global 'vega' or 'vl' variables.