# react-vega and react-vega tooltips

Tags: reactjs, tooltip, vega, vega-lite

I'm using `react-vega-lite`.

In official examples:

https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/

https://vega.github.io/react-vega-lite/

https://vega.github.io/react-vega/

`vega-lite` (without react) has a tooltip by default
`react-vega` allows to handle onSignalTooltip event.

So, I have 2 questions:
1) Is it possible to turn on tooltip with `react-vega` (`react-vega-lite`)?
2) Does `react-vega-lite` support `onSignalTooltip` or I need to switch to Vega?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `vega-tooltip` package as a dependency, then import the `Handler` class from it and pass an instance through the `tooltip` parameter of the `VegaLite` component:

```
import { Handler } from 'vega-tooltip';

...

<VegaLite spec={spec} data={barData} tooltip={new Handler().call} />
```